# How to automate gdb core dumping when receiving signal

Tags: c++, gdb, signals, gdbserver

I want to avoid the situation in which you forget to generate the core dump file after application got `SIGSEGV`, you leave gdb and you lost the information about that crash.

What I'm looking for is the analogue to `commands` (for breakpoints), so I can script a set of commands to execute when my app receives a signal.

Something beeing executed after each command could work too, just like `display` does. The point here is that I couldn't find how to check if X signal was generated.

At first, I prefer it to be something to configure inside gdb. By that, I mean not having to change how app/gdb are beeing launched.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your gdb supports the [`catch signal`](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Set-Catchpoints.html) command, you can script it just like a breakpoint.

```
$ gdb ab
(gdb) list
1   main()
2   {
3       abort();
4   }
(gdb) catch signal SIGABRT
Catchpoint 1 (signal SIGABRT)
(gdb) commands
Type commands for breakpoint(s) 1, one per line.
>generate-core-file 
>end
(gdb) run
Catchpoint 1 (signal SIGABRT), 0x00007ffff7a4692f in raise ()
   from /lib64/libc.so.6
Saved corefile core.2097
```